# Не работает reverse()

Tags: laravel, laravel5

С помощью Ajax вызываю такую функцию

```
$data = Generation::where('model_id', $request->id)->get()->reverse();
            return response()->json($data);
```

не работет `reverse()`;

Comment: В каком смысле "не работает"?

Comment: Без reverse() возращает Array(2), а с reverse() {0: {…}, 1: {…}}

Comment: Сперва реверс, а потом `->get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прекрасно работает. Но Вы видимо не прочитали как...
Результат возвращается с оригинальными ключами.

```
$collection = collect(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);

$reversed = $collection->reverse();

$reversed->all();

/*
    [
        4 => 'e',
        3 => 'd',
        2 => 'c',
        1 => 'b',
        0 => 'a',
    ]
*/
```